# What does this code do, and what does it look like in C?

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, disassembly, ida

I'm using IDA to disassemble a file, and one of the sections contained this. What is this doing? What would it look like in C?

I believe it pushes edx onto the stack, and converts it to an integer using _atoi, but what is left in eax after that, and why is it comparing it to 5?

```
mov     ecx, [ebp+argv]
mov     edx, [ecx+4]
push    edx             ; char *
call    _atoi
add     esp, 4
mov     [ebp+var_60], eax
cmp     [ebp+var_60], 5
jle     short loc_401167
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C code would look like this

```
int var_60;
if ( (var_60 = atoi( argv[1] )) > 5 )
{
    // execute the instructions after the 'jle' instruction, e.g.
    printf( "Invalid argument\n" );
    exit( 1 );
}
```

In other words, the code checks that the first argument to the program is a number that's less than or equal to 5. It also saves the converted value for later use.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I appreciate it.

Comment: Commenting again for a follow-up. Your edit answered my next question, thanks!

Comment: @AustinDonley Yup, it occurred to me that there's not much point in checking the program arguments unless you're going to do something with them :)

Comment: @AustinDonley: it's also pretty crappy code.  Any decent compiler should use `cmp     eax, 5`, instead of using `cmp` with the memory operand you just stored to.  (unless the source says `volatile int var_60`, or was compiled without optimization.)

Comment: Yeah it's not pretty. It's meant as a learning thing so it's some wonky code to disassemble, not meant to be really useful code.